# Check for css class in twig file which works fine on vue.js

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, twig, drupal-8

I am basically developing a twig file, I am very new to drupal 8

So previously i had a Vue file where i have this code snippet

```
<div class="dropdown-menu":aria-labelledby="menu.class" v-if="menu.class.includes('dropdown')">
```

Where menu.class is array of items

This line will execute only if the menu.class includes the style dropdown, which is working totally fine.

Now i am replicating the same thing in a twig fine and added this code

```
{% if menu.class.hasClass('dropdown') %}
                
 <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="{{ menu.class }}">
 </div>

{% endif %}
```

Here is the menu array

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array
        
        ( [title] => Home [path] => / 
        [class] => no-break-class )
        
[2] => Array
    (
        [title] => CFO
        [path] => 
        [class] => dropdown-two-col
        [children] => Array )
    )
```

But The code is not entering the loop. Is there any other syntax for it. Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I don't think twig recognize your menu.class.hasClass('dropdown'), you can try dump this variable to see if it existed.
If you want to check if value exists in array twig:

```
{% if 'dropdown' in menu.class %}
```

To check if key exists:

```
{% if 'dropdown' in menu.class|keys %}
```

Comment: I have tried with `{% if 'dropdown' in menu.class %}` but not working

Comment: Can you post your array menu.class here ?

Comment: In your case, you have to loop through the array to detect if your array contain the value "dropdown", twig has for loop to do it. You can take a look https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/for.html#adding-a-condition.

Another method is writing a custom twig filter for handling your business, this is document for Symfony, but you can take a look to use it for your situation.
https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html